# How can I create a toggle 'view to selected' hotkey?

Tags: customization, shortcut

I've changed my 'view to selected' hotkey and would like to make it a toggle shortcut that allows me either to focus on the selected object or toggle back to the whole scene. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: How would Blender know when to focus on a single object or the whole scene?

Comment: Let's say it would toggle focus in between the selected object and a camera angle the fits all the geometry, this way you can visualize back and forth small parts of a complex geometry or scene for example without having to hide everything else...understand?

Comment: What is the problem with NumpadDelete (view selected) and Shift C (view all)? You could simply map them closer together on your keyboard. What would happen when you press View All, then zoom out and the toggle your desired function? Would it do view all or view selected. As Duarte mentioned this feature is poorly outlined in your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use the "forward slash (/)"  in the number pad on your keyboard to toggle 'View Selected'

View to Selected

Goto>Tool Shelf
Look for "Display Tab" at the corners where there are other Tabs. You will see "View to Selected" in the display tab options.!

[Click here to view image illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiP8E.jpg)

Comment: Yeah but that's the isolate isn't it? I'd like to be able to switch between 'view selected' and the 'home' button functionality in the same shortcut.

Comment: If you mean "without hidden other objects" then you are talking of "view to selected"

Comment: I never meant hiding other objects in scene, but yeah...'view to selected'

Comment: Have you been able to get what you are looking for from my edited answer?

Comment: I get what you mean now, thanks...but it was just mispelling...the issue remains the same; What do I have to do to have both 'view to selected' and 'view the whole scene'(like the HOME button) in a toggle shortcut?

Comment: If your question has been solved, please mark it as solved.

Comment: It hasn't;

'the issue remains the same; What do I have to do to have both 'view to selected' and 'view the whole scene'(like the HOME button) in a toggle shortcut?'

Answer (score -1):

For creating shortcuts

Goto>File>User Preferences
Under User Preferences,
Goto>Input tab>3D View>3D View (Global)

Additional shortcuts can be created there